# Does the .dispose() method do anything at all?

Tags: vb.net, memory, dispose

I was experimenting with ways to get rid of some memory leaks within my application the other day when I realized that I know virtually nothing about cleaning up my resources.  I did some research, and hoped that just calling the .dispose() would solve all of my problems.  We have a table in our database that contains about 65,000 records.  Obviously when I fill my dataset from the data adapter, the memory usage can get pretty high.  When I called the dispose method on the dataset, I was surprised to find out that NONE of the memory got released.  Why did this happen?  Clearing the dataset doesn't help either.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) and thus [Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(VS.71).aspx) is not used to reduced memory pressure, although in some cases it might, but instead used for deterministic cleanup.

Consider this, you construct an object that maintains an active and open connection to your database server. This connection uses resources, both on your machine, and the server.

You could of course just leave the object be when you're done with it, and eventually it'll get picked up by the garbage collector, but suppose you want to make sure at least the resources gets freed, and thus the connection closed, when you're done with it. This is where [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx).[Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(VS.71).aspx) comes into play.

It is used to clean up resources managed by the object.

It will, however, not free the managed memory allocated to the object. This is still left to the garbage collector, that will kick in at some later time to do that.

Do you actually have a memory problem, or do you just look at the memory usage in Task Manager or similar and go "that's a bit high."?

If the latter, then you should just leave it be for now. .NET will run garbage collection more often if you have less memory available, so unless you're in a situation where you get, or might suspect you will get soon, a memory overflow condition, you're probably not going to have any problems.

Let me explain what I mean by "run less often".

If you have 8GB of memory in your machine, and only have Windows and Notepad running, most of that memory will be available. When you now run your program, even if it loads minor data blocks into memory, you can keep doing that for a long time, and memory usage will steadily grow. Exactly when the GC will kick in and try to reduce your memory footprint I don't know, but I can almost guarantee you that you will wonder why it gets so high.

Let's just for the sake of the argument say that your program will eventually use 2GB of memory.

Now, if you run your program on a machine that has less memory available, GC will occur more often, and will kick in on a lower limit, which might keep the memory usage below 500MB or possibly even less.

The important part to note here is that in order for you to get an accurate picture of how much memory application actually *requires*, then you can't rely on Task Manager or similar ways to measure it, you need something more targetted.

Comment: My program can get up to  700,164k.  Not good considering my customers might have lower end computers.

Comment: which means you didn't read my answer. Try loading up several large applications so that before you start your own program, you have less than 700,164k memory available (including virtual memory). Then try to load it up, it will probably still work, unless you're loading more than that of data into memory for usage, in which case gc won't help at all, you just need to reduce the amount of data you process at any given time.

Answer (score 4):

Calling Dispose() will only release unmanaged resources, such as file handles, database connections, unmanaged memory, etc. It will **not** release garbage collected memory.

Garbage collected memory will only get released at the next collection. Usually when the application domain memory is deamed full.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to point out something here that hasn't been explicitly mentioned: calling `Dispose()` will only clean up (free) unmanaged resources if the developer of the component has coded it.

What I mean is this: if you suspect you have a memory leak, calling `Dispose()` is not going to fix it *if the original developer has done a lousy job and not correctly freed up unmanaged resources*. For a bit more info, [check this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/clyon/archive/2004/09/21/232445.aspx). Take note of the statement *The behaviour of Dispose is defined by the developer.*

Answer (score 1):

Some objects will ask one or more other entities to do something on its behalf until further notice, to the detriment of other entities.  If an object which did so were to disappear without informing the former entities that their services were no longer needed, those entities would continue to uselessly act on behalf of an object that no longer needed them, to the continuing detriment of other entities that would want to use them.

In many cases, for an object "George" to tell an outside entity "Joe" that its services were no longer needed, George would have to know that *its* services were no longer needed.  There are two normal means via which that can happen in .NET, finalization and `IDIsposable`.

If an object overrides a method called `Finalize`, then when the object is created the .NET garbage collector will add it to a list of objects with registered finalizers.  If the GC discovers that there exists no rooted reference to the object other than that list, the GC will remove the object from that list and add it to a strongly-rooted queue of objects which should have their `Finalize` method called as soon as possible.  Such an object can then use its `Finalize` method to inform other entities that their services are no longer required.

Although finalization-based cleanup can sometimes work, there's no guarantee of timeliness.  At one point during the design of .net Microsoft may have intended that finalization would be the primary cleanup method, but for a variety of reasons it cannot safely be relied upon.

The other cleanup approach, which should be the focus of one's efforts, is `IDisposable`.  Basically, the idea behind `IDisposable` is simple: for every object that implements `IDisposable`, there should be one entity (generally either an object or a nested execution scope) which is responsible for ensuring that that object's `IDisposable.Dispose` method will get called sometime within the lifetime of the universe (which would imply sometime while a reference to the object still exists), and preferably as soon as code can tell that the object's services will no longer be required.

Note that `IDisposable.Dispose` generally promises that any outside entities which had been asked to do something on an object's behalf will be told that they no longer need to do so, but such a promise does not imply that the number of entities is non-zero.  If an object hasn't asked any outside entities to do anything on its behalf, then delivering a message "all" such entities doesn't require doing anything at all.  On the other hand, the fact that a `Dispose` method may do nothing in some cases doesn't mean that it's guaranteed never to do anything in any case, nor that failure to call it in those cases where it would do something won't have detrimental effects.