# Why can an image not call Dispose on its own?

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, bitmap, dispose

When I want to make sure that an image / bitmap is really gone, I need to call

```
MyBitmap.Dispose()
MyBitmap = Nothing
```

Why is the call to .Dispose() necessary?

Why can't I simply say

```
MyBitmap = Nothing
```

?

I'm not good at C++, but I suspect that the underlying image / bitmap class knows when it's about to die, so why doesn't it call .Dispose on its own and lets the user take care of that?

Comment: *I suspect that the underlying image / bitmap class knows when it's about to die* Your suspicion is wrong. The garbage collector will call the finalizer on the bitmap class at some non-deterministic point in the future, so to deterministically release resources the call to `Dispose` is necessary.

Comment: [Don't set the object to Nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2785/4934172), it's not necessary _and not recommended_. Calling `Dispose()` is what's necessary. Check this post for more info: [Does the .dispose() method do anything at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2024021/4934172)

Comment: @ta.speot.is I mean when I set the object to nothing. That destroys the object and doesn't let the GC do it, right?

Comment: No it doesn't. It merely removes that variable's reference to the object. The object will continue to live until the GC runs and collects it (which will only happen if there are no more references to it).

Comment: As far as I know, `Dispose` exists _exactly_ for objects that the garbage controller can't clean up automatically...

Comment: @VisualVincent Thank you so much, you're a great teacher. I think anybody would profit from your comment as an answer to my question. I have never seen this explained so well.

Comment: I'd recommend reading Eric Lippert's treatise on the hazards of finalizers: https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/  The many issues with finalizers are the main reason for using the `Dispose` pattern to reclaim any resources that aren't managed objects.  In fact, the object *can* call `Dispose` on its own (the finalizer typically will include such a call), but for the various reasons Eric discusses, it's better to manage the lifetime of non-managed resources explicitly when you can.

Comment: Glad I can help! Though a complete answer would have to include what Nyerguds and Craig mentioned (which I do know about, though not enough to write an adequate answer :). The GC does automatically collect the _managed object_, however as the others said you want to call `Dispose()` to dispose of any unmanaged memory lying around (assuming the object has properly implemented cleanup).