# Saving multiple images as buffers/memory streams to the same table at the same time

Tags: vb.net

I'm relatively new to coding and entirely self taught, so please have patience with me.
I've been scouring the internet for an answer to this, but everything I've found is either waaaaaaayyy too technical and looks like ancient greek, or doesn't even apply to my situation.

I'm developing an app for work for my managers to record employee information.  The page I'm currently working on is for injuries, however this will apply to multiple pages if I can figure it out.  I know I'm probably over-complicating something and it's going to be a stupid answer but I've tried everything I can think of so far.

What I'm trying to do is capture handwritten notes as images and then save them to a database for us in the office to type up and translate if needed.  (a lot of my managers don't type) but this would apply to collecting multiple signatures as well i.e. on write ups.

I've got the images saved, but when it comes time to write them to the database, the first image will write just fine, but the second one I start getting the "Data type mismatch in the criteria expression" error.

I've tried isolating the 2nd and third images to see if it's a syntax issue, but I still get the error.  I've rebuilt the database table to make sure the destination field is an OLE object, same error.  I've been searching for a few days now for the answer and I'm not finding it, so if someone can please help.

I know it's going to be something silly like not disposing of something in the right place, but that is beyond my current knowledge.  Thank you in advance for any help.

```
`Private Sub AddState(pathD As String, PathC As String, PathS As String)   
 'Determination
    ' EXIT IF IMAGE NOT SELECTED
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathD) Then Exit Sub

    'GET IMAGE DATA VIA MEMORY STREAM
    Dim imgD As Image = Image.FromFile(pathD)
    Dim msD As New MemoryStream()
    imgD.Save(msD, imgD.RawFormat)
    Dim bufferD As Byte() = msD.GetBuffer

    'Comments 
    ' EXIT IF IMAGE NOT SELECTED
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(PathC) Then Exit Sub

    'GET IMAGE DATA VIA MEMORY STREAM
    Dim imgC As Image = Image.FromFile(PathC)
    Dim msC As New MemoryStream()
    imgC.Save(msC, imgC.RawFormat)
    Dim bufferC As Byte() = msC.GetBuffer

    'Supervisor Signature
    ' EXIT IF IMAGE NOT SELECTED
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(PathS) Then Exit Sub

    'GET IMAGE DATA VIA MEMORY STREAM
    Dim imgS As Image = Image.FromFile(PathS)
    Dim msS As New MemoryStream()
    imgS.Save(msS, imgS.RawFormat)
    Dim bufferS As Byte() = msS.GetBuffer

    access.AddParam("@AccID", lblAccID.Text)
    access.AddParam("@EmpName", lblEmpName.Text)
    access.AddParam("@DOA", lblInjDate.Text)
    access.AddParam("@DOR", Today)
    access.AddParam("@Boss", cbxSupName.Text)
    access.AddParam("@Phone", txtPhone.Text)
    access.AddParam("@RepDate", dpRepDate.Value.Date)
    access.AddParam("@RepTime", txtRepTime.Text & " " & Time)
    access.AddParam("@DrUs", DrUs)
    access.AddParam("@DrThem", DrThem)
    access.AddParam("@Facility", cbxFacility.SelectedItem)
    access.AddParam("@Missed", Missed)
    access.AddParam("@DetType", txtDetermine.Text)
    access.AddParam("@DetFile", lblDetFileLoc.Text)
    access.AddParam("@CommentType", txtComments.Text)
    access.AddParam("@CommFile", lblComFileLoc.Text)
    access.AddParam("@SigFile", lblSigFileLoc.Text)
    access.AddParam("@DetWrite", bufferD)
    access.AddParam("@CommentWrite", bufferC)
    access.AddParam("@SupSig", bufferS)


    access.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO AccSup(AccID, InjEmp, InjDate, RepDate, Supervisor, SupPhone, DateReported, " &
                     "TimeReported, DrUs, DrThem, Facility, MissedWork, SupDetermination, DetFileLoc, " &
                     "SupComments,CommFileLoc, SigFileLoc, Determination, Comment, Sig)" &
                     "VALUES (@AccID, @EmpName, @DOA, @DOR, @Boss, @Phone, @RepDate, " &
                     "@RepTime, @DrUs, @DrThem, @Facility, @Missed, @DetType, @DetFile, " &
                     "@CommentType, @CommFile, @SigFile, @DetWrite, @CommentWrite, @SupSig) ")

    ' REPORT ERRORS
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(access.exception) Then MsgBox(access.exception)

    MsgBox("Report Added")
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSubmit.Click
    AddState(lblDetFileLoc.Text, lblComFileLoc.Text, lblSigFileLoc.Text)
End Sub`
```

dbcontrol

```
Public Class dbControlBU
    'CREATE YOUR DB CONNECTION
    Private DBCon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
                                         "Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Documents\Open Enrollment\OpenEnrollment.accdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=****")

    ' PREPARE DB COMMAND
    Private DBCmd As OleDbCommand

    'DB DATA
    Public DBDA As OleDbDataAdapter
    Public DBDT As DataTable

    ' QUERY PARAMETERS
    Public Params As New List(Of OleDbParameter)

    ' QUERY STATISTICS
    Public RecordCount As Integer
    Public exception As String

    Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String)
        ' RESET QUERY STATS
        RecordCount = 0
        exception = ""

        Try
            ' OPEN A CONNECTION
            DBCon.Open()

            ' CREATE DB COMMAND
            DBCmd = New OleDbCommand(Query, DBCon)

            ' LOAD PARAMS INTO DB COMMAND
            Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))

            ' CLEAR PARAMS LIST
            Params.Clear()

            ' EXECUTE COMMAND AND FILL DATATABLE
            DBDT = New DataTable
            DBDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(DBCmd)
            RecordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)

        Catch ex As Exception
            exception = ex.Message
        End Try

        'CLOSE YOUR CONNECTION
        If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()
    End Sub

    'INCLUDE QUERY & COMMAND PARAMETERS
    Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
        Dim NewParam As New OleDbParameter(Name, Value)
        Params.Add(NewParam)
    End Sub

    'Schema Restrictions
    ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716722%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

    Public Function GetTables() As List(Of String)
        Dim lstTables As New List(Of String)
        Dim restrictions As String() = New String() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"}

        Try
            DBCon.Open()
            DBDT = DBCon.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions)

            For Each r As DataRow In DBDT.Rows
                lstTables.Add(r("TABLE_NAME"))
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()
        End Try

        Return lstTables
    End Function

    Public Function GetColumnsByTable(TableName As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim lstColumns As New List(Of String)
        Dim restrictions As String() = New String() {Nothing, Nothing, TableName, Nothing}

        Try
            DBCon.Open()
            DBDT = DBCon.GetSchema("Columns", restrictions)

            For Each r As DataRow In DBDT.Rows
                lstColumns.Add(r("COLUMN_NAME"))
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBCon.Close()
        End Try

        Return lstColumns
    End Function
```

The error I'm getting is
[image]

It happens after I go through my app and his "Submit" and it runs the Insert Into statement into the Access Database.
I have rebuilt the columns in Access to make sure they're the right datatype and I hadn't accidentally changed something somewhere. That didn't help.
The 1st image will save, but 2nd and 3rd images get this error.  I've tried not including the 1st image.  completely deleted it from the Insert into statement, I figured if I did that, then Image 2 would save, but not 3.
no- both of them still didn't save. Got the same error.
I tried removing both images 1 and 2 to see if just image 2 was problematic. Same error. At that point the computer almost went out the window.

Here is the error I got after removing the Catch Statement.

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException   HResult=0x80040E07   Message=Data
> type mismatch in criteria expression.   Source=System.Data
> StackTrace:    at
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
> hr)    at
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
> dbParams, Object& executeResult)    at
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object&
> executeResult)    at
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
> behavior, Object& executeResult)    at
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
> behavior, String method)    at
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> at
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
> dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
> String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
> System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32
> startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior
> behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable
> dataTable)    at EmployeeManager_New.dbControl.ExecQuery(String Query)
> in C:\Users\CatWisian\Lone Star Calf Ranch\Lone Star Calf Ranch Site -
> Documents (1)\General\Cat Apps\Employee
> Manager-New\EmployeeManager_New\dbControl.vb:line 42    at
> EmployeeManager_New.SupStat.AddState(String pathD, String PathC,
> String PathS) in C:\Users\CatWisian\Lone Star Calf Ranch\Lone Star
> Calf Ranch Site - Documents (1)\General\Cat Apps\Employee
> Manager-New\EmployeeManager_New\English\Injury\SupStat.vb:line 639
> at EmployeeManager_New.SupStat.cmdSubmit_Click(Object sender,
> EventArgs e) in C:\Users\CatWisian\Lone Star Calf Ranch\Lone Star Calf
> Ranch Site - Documents (1)\General\Cat Apps\Employee
> Manager-New\EmployeeManager_New\English\Injury\SupStat.vb:line 653
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
> button, Int32 clicks)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
> m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
> hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
> at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
> dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
> reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
> reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
> Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
> at
> Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
> at
> Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[]
> commandLine)    at EmployeeManager_New.My.MyApplication.Main(String[]
> Args) in :line 83
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> [External Code]
> EmployeeManager_New.dbControl.ExecQuery(String) in dbControl.vb
> EmployeeManager_New.SupStat.AddState(String, String, String) in SupStat.vb
> EmployeeManager_New.SupStat.cmdSubmit_Click(Object, System.EventArgs) in SupStat.vb
> [External Code]

Newest error code

```
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at EmployeeManager_New.dbControl.ExecQuery(String Query) in C:\Users\CatWisian\Lone Star Calf Ranch\Lone Star Calf Ranch Site - Documents (1)\General\Cat Apps\Employee Manager-New\EmployeeManager_New\dbControl.vb:line 40
   at EmployeeManager_New.SupStat.AddState(String pathD, String PathC, String PathS) in C:\Users\CatWisian\Lone Star Calf Ranch\Lone Star Calf Ranch Site - Documents (1)\General\Cat Apps\Employee Manager-New\EmployeeManager_New\English\Injury\SupStat.vb:line 631
   at EmployeeManager_New.SupStat.cmdSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\CatWisian\Lone Star Calf Ranch\Lone Star Calf Ranch Site - Documents (1)\General\Cat Apps\Employee Manager-New\EmployeeManager_New\English\Injury\SupStat.vb:line 648
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at EmployeeManager_New.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :line 83
```

And still getting the same "Data Criteria Mismatch" error. I'm gonna start banging my head on my desk.

```
  at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at EmployeeManager_New.dbControl.ExecQuery(String Query) in C:\Users\CatWisian\Lone Star Calf Ranch\Lone Star Calf Ranch Site - Documents (1)\General\Cat Apps\Employee Manager-New\EmployeeManager_New\dbControl.vb:line 40
   at EmployeeManager_New.SupStat.AddState(String pathD, String PathC, String PathS) in C:\Users\CatWisian\Lone Star Calf Ranch\Lone Star Calf Ranch Site - Documents (1)\General\Cat Apps\Employee Manager-New\EmployeeManager_New\English\Injury\SupStat.vb:line 631
   at EmployeeManager_New.SupStat.cmdSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\CatWisian\Lone Star Calf Ranch\Lone Star Calf Ranch Site - Documents (1)\General\Cat Apps\Employee Manager-New\EmployeeManager_New\English\Injury\SupStat.vb:line 648
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at EmployeeManager_New.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :line 83
```

Here's what I have in Access.  Maybe someone can see if the problem's there.  I don't think it should be though.  I've rebuilt this table already to make sure it had the data types I wanted in case I had fat fingered something.

[image]

I did test the entire thing before I started with the images as I knew I was venturing into new territory with them, and everything worked ok at that time, so I can safely say it's the images causing the issue.
It may be an access thing.  I tend to dream big on these things and then have to get brought back down to reality when I find out Access isn't capable of doing what I wanted it to do.  Sql is not an option in this case as the guys are in a barn with a spotty internet connection as it is, so I have to keep things as local as possible.

Comment: Great effort! Well done on teaching yourself. Can you comment on what type of object 'access' is in this code? It would be wise to put any objects that support IDisposable into a Using block to ensure they close / dispose correctly. Certainly the MemoryStream can be disposed and if you're not clearing the params off the access object, they'll need to be cleared away too.

Comment: "access" is referring to my dbcontrol i.e. Private access as new dbcontrol

Comment: Instead of having just one instance of an OleDbConnection, you should create a new one every time you want to use one and dispose of it as soon as you're finished with that query. As Andrew Mortimer wrote, you can use the [Using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) to do that; [here's a small example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#examples) for the similar SqlConnection.

Comment: This is in a class so it only gets called when needed and then disposed of. 
I don’t believe that is the problem anyways unless it is an impossibility that I don’t know of. I’m trying to write 2-3 images within the same sub, so if that isn’t possible (could totally be the issue) then I would have to write a sub for each image.

Comment: Is there anything else that happens after writing the first image, and before the second? Can you confirm the exact SQL being executed as the error occurs?

Comment: @CatherineWisian If that is how you want to do it, then you will need to follow these easy instructions [Dispose class vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19097700/1115360) so that you can explicitly call .Dispose() on the OleDbConnection - it is necessary so that "unmanaged resources" can be cleaned up.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer They are all in the same Insert Into statement, so basically they're just separate columns in the database.   Previously, I was saving every image into separate tables, which i know is good database management, but for this purpose, I clean this database out monthly once the reports have been processed into my parent sql database where everything is split out and these images are moot. so that hasn't been a concern- I just needed a down and dirty way to get info from my computer illiterate managers to me in the office.

Comment: @AndrewMorton If i'm understanding you correctly- the memory stream/buffer is hanging on to the first image, and doesn't take the second image as a result.    My question now is- why is it still doing that, when i skip the first image, and only try to save the second image.  I've tried isolating both of the latter images and don't have any images in front of them and I get the same results.

Comment: @CatherineWisian (1) I suggest that you comment out the Catch part for now so that you get to see the entire error message, which might include which column it is complaining about. (2) Also, it would be better to preserve the type of the parameter instead of regarding everything as Object. As `Params` is Public, you could write `access.Params.Add(New OleDbParameter With {(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@whatever", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarWChar, .Value = somevariable})` (I like the With way as it lets me see the names of the, errr, parameters of the parameter) instead of AddParam

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for the help.  I understood the Catch part of it, but the second part started veering into Greek territory.  I'm just not sure where to apply these changes, in the class or on the form.  i posted the error I got above.

Comment: @CatherineWisian Sometimes error messages take you straight to the problem... that one not so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some entities use "unmanaged resources" which need to be explicitly taken care of by calling [Dispose()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2024021/1115360) on them. There is a way to have that happen automatically for you: the [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) statement.

As it happens, both database connections (e.g. OleDbConnection) and the Image type are such entities.

Here is an example of how you could modify your code:

```
Private Sub AddState(pathD As String, PathC As String, PathS As String)
    ' EXIT EARLY IF IMAGE NOT SELECTED
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathD) OrElse
       String.IsNullOrEmpty(PathC) OrElse
       String.IsNullOrEmpty(PathS) Then

        Exit Sub

    End If

    Dim bufferD As Byte()
    Dim bufferC As Byte()
    Dim bufferS As Byte()

    'GET IMAGE DATA VIA MEMORY STREAM
    Using imgD As Image = Image.FromFile(pathD),
          imgC As Image = Image.FromFile(PathC),
          imgS As Image = Image.FromFile(PathS)

        'Determination
        Dim msD As New MemoryStream()
        imgD.Save(msD, imgD.RawFormat)
        bufferD = msD.GetBuffer()

        'Comments 
        Dim msC As New MemoryStream()
        imgC.Save(msC, imgC.RawFormat)
        bufferC = msC.GetBuffer()

        'Supervisor Signature
        Dim msS As New MemoryStream()
        imgS.Save(msS, imgS.RawFormat)
        bufferS = msS.GetBuffer()

    End Using

    Dim access As New DbControlBu()

    'TODO: Fill in the OleDbType for every parameter
    access.AddParam("@AccID", OleDbType.VarChar, lblAccID.Text)
    access.AddParam("@EmpName", OleDbType.VarChar, lblEmpName.Text)
    access.AddParam("@DOA", lblInjDate.Text)
    access.AddParam("@DOR", OleDbType.Date, Today)
    access.AddParam("@Boss", cbxSupName.Text)
    access.AddParam("@Phone", txtPhone.Text)
    access.AddParam("@RepDate", dpRepDate.Value.Date)
    access.AddParam("@RepTime", txtRepTime.Text & " " & Time)
    access.AddParam("@DrUs", DrUs)
    access.AddParam("@DrThem", DrThem)
    access.AddParam("@Facility", cbxFacility.SelectedItem)
    access.AddParam("@Missed", Missed)
    access.AddParam("@DetType", txtDetermine.Text)
    access.AddParam("@DetFile", lblDetFileLoc.Text)
    access.AddParam("@CommentType", txtComments.Text)
    access.AddParam("@CommFile", lblComFileLoc.Text)
    access.AddParam("@SigFile", lblSigFileLoc.Text)
    access.AddParam("@DetWrite", OleDbType.LongVarBinary, bufferD)
    access.AddParam("@CommentWrite", OleDbType.LongVarBinary, bufferC)
    access.AddParam("@SupSig", OleDbType.LongVarBinary, bufferS)


    access.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO AccSup(AccID, InjEmp, InjDate, RepDate, Supervisor, SupPhone, DateReported, " &
                 "TimeReported, DrUs, DrThem, Facility, MissedWork, SupDetermination, DetFileLoc, " &
                 "SupComments,CommFileLoc, SigFileLoc, Determination, Comment, Sig)" &
                 "VALUES (@AccID, @EmpName, @DOA, @DOR, @Boss, @Phone, @RepDate, " &
                 "@RepTime, @DrUs, @DrThem, @Facility, @Missed, @DetType, @DetFile, " &
                 "@CommentType, @CommFile, @SigFile, @DetWrite, @CommentWrite, @SupSig) ")

    ' REPORT STATUS
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(access.exception) Then
        MsgBox("Report Added")
    Else
        MsgBox(access.exception)
    End If

End Sub
```

dbcontrol

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class DbControlBu
    ' DB CONNECTION STRING
    Private Const connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""C:\Users\Public\Documents\Open Enrollment\OpenEnrollment.accdb"";Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=****"

    'DB DATA
    Public DBDA As OleDbDataAdapter
    Public DBDT As DataTable

    ' QUERY PARAMETERS
    Public Params As New List(Of OleDbParameter)

    ' QUERY STATISTICS
    Public recordCount As Integer
    Public exception As String

    Public Sub ExecQuery(query As String)
        ' RESET QUERY STATS
        recordCount = 0
        exception = ""

        Try
            Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr),
                   cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
                ' OPEN A CONNECTION
                conn.Open()

                ' LOAD PARAMS INTO DB COMMAND
                Params.ForEach(Sub(p) cmd.Parameters.Add(p))

                ' CLEAR PARAMS LIST
                Params.Clear()

                ' EXECUTE COMMAND AND FILL DATATABLE
                DBDT = New DataTable()
                DBDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                recordCount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)

            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            exception = ex.Message
        End Try

    End Sub

    'INCLUDE QUERY & COMMAND PARAMETERS
    Public Sub AddParam(name As String, dbType As OleDbType, value As Object)
        Dim newParam As New OleDbParameter() With {.ParameterName = name, .OleDbType = dbType, .Value = value}
        Params.Add(NewParam)
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
        Dim NewParam As New OleDbParameter(Name, Value)
        Params.Add(NewParam)
    End Sub

    'Schema Restrictions
    ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716722%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

    Public Function GetTables() As List(Of String)
        Dim lstTables As New List(Of String)
        Dim restrictions As String() = New String() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"}

        Try
            Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr)
                conn.Open()
                DBDT = conn.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions)

                For Each r As DataRow In DBDT.Rows
                    lstTables.Add(r("TABLE_NAME").ToString()) ' Add .ToString()
                Next
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Return lstTables

    End Function

    Public Function GetColumnsByTable(tableName As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim lstColumns As New List(Of String)
        Dim restrictions As String() = New String() {Nothing, Nothing, tableName, Nothing}

        Try
            Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr)
                conn.Open()
                DBDT = conn.GetSchema("Columns", restrictions)

                For Each r As DataRow In DBDT.Rows
                    lstColumns.Add(r("COLUMN_NAME").ToString()) ' Add .ToString()
                Next

            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Return lstColumns

    End Function

End Class
```

I can't test it, but hopefully it gives you enough information to fix your code.

(Although a MemoryStream has a Dispose method, it is the one case where you don't need to call that.)

Comment: Once again sir you've just beaten me to an answer! I was about half way through my version..

Comment: @AndrewMortimer Please let me know if I've done anything silly in that answer and I'll make appropriate adjustments :)

Comment: Oh I wouldn't say anything was wrong there. I was looking at a version using 'dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()' as I thought it would be more appropriate for the insert, as the result wasn't needed in a datatable. Likewise it would be great to have the code/db local to test. Hopefully this gets Catherine closer to resolving the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for spelling it out like that! of course I see this as I'm about to walk out the door to go to an appointment so I'll try it either tonight or tomorrow morning.   Ironically- I had something similar to this in one of my previous attempts, but minus the using stuff, but the cleaned up top half.

Comment: so I've made the changes but now I've got the red squiggles under anything with the OleDbType in the middle and I'm getting an error that says "Too many arguments to "public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)'.  I deleted the OleDbType and was able to run a test and got an error again.    I'm attaching above as it's too long again.  probably more nonsense.

Comment: @CatherineWisian If you take another look, you'll see that I added an overload of the AddParam function that takes three parameters, as well as putting the Using statements in for the database queries.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I was going to mess with it more and try something along those lines, but payroll takes priority.  I'll hit this again once that is done.  :)

Comment: So I tested this over the weekend.  In my existing project it doesn't work. but when I built a fresh database and did a test form it worked beautifully which leads me to believe it's something to do with my database.  I guess I'll be re-building that table again, if not the whole database.  At least I know it's possible now.    Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Just re-created the table it was writing to and very carefully rewrote the code and everything worked great.  I was thisclose to having it, but b/c of that little bug i thought I was going crazy.  Thank you everyone for the help.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: According to the [OleDbParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) documentation _The OLE DB.NET Framework Data Provider uses positional parameters that are marked with a question mark (?) instead of named parameters_.